# Qt 5.12.1 QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Linux Mint 19.1

Работаю в Qt Creator с C++. Пытаясь подключиться к MySQL вижу такую проблему:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
Cannot open database: QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
```

По адресу:

```
/home/marko/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers
```

следующие файлы:

```
libqsqlite.so
libqsqlite.so.debug
libqsqlmysql.so
libqsqlmysql.so.debug
libqsqlpsql.so
libqsqlpsql.so.debug
```

libmysqlclient и libssl уже стоят(проверял в Synaptic)

выхлоп ldd

```
ldd ~/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd29593000)
libQt5Sql.so.5 => /home/marko/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007fa092088000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/marko/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fa0918f0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa0916d0000)
libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa091340000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa090fa0000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa090d88000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa090990000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa090770000)
libicui18n.so.56 => /home/marko/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007fa0902d0000)
libicuuc.so.56 => /home/marko/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007fa08ff18000)
libicudata.so.56 => /home/marko/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007fa08e530000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa08e328000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa08e120000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa08de08000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa0924e8000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fa08db90000)
```

По идее я должен собрать исходники драйвера для СУБД, но я не совсем понимаю, что конкретно нужно делать. В линуксе и программировании не спец(пока что)
Как заставить драйвер СУБД работать при таком раскладе вещей?

Comment: `libqsqlmysql.so` и есть «драйвер», не хватает `libmysqlclient.so.18`, обычно используется системная веерсия, скорей всего будет достаточно просто установить соответствующий пакет, обычно пакета так и называется `libmysqlclient18` или `libmariadbclient18` (или вроде того).

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. А вообще в чем весь прикол компиляции драйверов в кьюте? Т.е. какой алгоритм общий для решения подобных проблем? Ибо я уже вижу не первый раз подобные вопросы.

Comment: в данном случае по выводу `ldd` видно, что `libmysqlclient.so.18` не найдена, самая простая причина этого, что она не установлена... драйверы СУБД загружаются динамически, а если отсутствует какая-либо библиотека, то они возвращаю ошибку вместо того чтобы просто сделать программу незапускаемой... Речь о сборке драйвера может идти при самостоятельной сборке Qt т.к. ЕМНИП в конфиге по умолчанию они не собираются...

Comment: Кроме того обычно, если нет особой необходимости, то все пользуются системной версией Qt из репозитариев и таких проблем не возникает т.к. всё необходимое подтягивается по зависимостям... ты же по незнанию или по каким-то ещё причинам решил установить дистрибутив с официального сайта (насколько я могу угадать), но в таком случае предполагается, что зависимые библиотеки, например X'овые, sql'евские и всякие другие нужно устанавливать самостоятельно...

Comment: хм... странно, но у меня вместо 18ой либы стоит 20ая... почему он её не хочет съедать? О_о
libmariadb18 поставил. Всё как было так и осталось

Comment: Стянул с packages.ubuntu.com этот пакет. Всё работает. Хотя ситуация с аналогичным пакетом остаётся непонятной...

Comment: не хочет съедать потому что, во-первых, `libmysqlclient` с обновлением мажорных версий ломает ABI, а, во-вторых, это отражено в том, что драйвер слинкован именно с _libmysqlclient.so.**18**_... и да, недосмотрел, в дебианах mariadb собирают со своим именем библиотеки, а совместимость обеспечивают с помощью пакета `libmariadb-dev-compat` — его тоже нужно установить... в данном случае также может потребоваться вручную создать ссылку: `ln -s libmariadbclient.so.18 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная проблема решается с помощью установки libmysqlclient18
У меня была установлена библиотека libmysqlclient20(на данный момент в репозиториях только она) и с ней кьют работать не захотел.

По словам пользователя Fat-Zer

> ibmysqlclient с обновлением мажорных версий ломает ABI, а, во-вторых, это отражено в том, что драйвер слинкован именно с libmysqlclient.so.**18**

Библиотека была скачана [отсюда. (Ссылка на packages.ubuntu.com)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/trusty/libmysqlclient18)